# required field not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello,

I am trying to implement "required" on my input fields in a form and onclick- submit, it goes to a function that calls a 3rd party function and passes the form to it.

I understand that "required" doesn't work with "onclick" but is there a way to go around it?

EDIT: I do not have any php or backend which is why Im calling a client to pass the form data.

Code:

```
<form id="signupform">
       <label for="name"> Name </label>
       <input type= "text" id="name" name="name" required>        
       <label for="emailaddr"> Email </label>
       <input type= "email" id="emailaddr" name="emailaddr" required>
       <button type="submit" onclick="callclient()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Just use the forms onsubmit, and then pass it on.

Comment: I used onsubmit as you suggested. However it does not call the function. Can you please elucidate how i would call the function if I replaced onclick with onsubmit in the above code ?
If this approach is wrong, can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also capture the submit event with jQuery and execute your function that way.

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xwvfuLv/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#signupform').on('submit', function(e){

       // Stop the form submission
       e.preventDefault();

       callClient();

    })
})

function callClient(){
    alert('client called.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet, using the onsubmit.

I'm returning false so the default submit is not called, this is likely why you think it's not working in your version.

```js
function callclient() {
  console.log('Client Called');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="signupform" onsubmit="return callclient();">
       <label for="name"> Name </label>
       <input type= "text" id="name" name="name" required>        
       <label for="emailaddr"> Email </label>
       <input type= "email" id="emailaddr" name="emailaddr" required>
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: My sincerest thanks for the help.
I am however, facing a new problem, as I have a "success.html" page after this and it is not loading, is there a way around that too?

Code: 
 function callClient() {
        /*call Client*/
        window.location.href = "success.html";
     }

Comment: That should work, you getting any errors in the console?.

Comment: did not get errors, it just did not call the required page. 
So, i used the jquery method above and it worked perfect